# Anyone know a php snippet for showing the first 200 characters of the most recent post?

Tags: posts, query

I wish I knew PHP as well as I do Rails. I'd imagine this is fairly intuitive.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wordpress has an inbuilt function called [`the_excerpt()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_excerpt) which echoes an excerpt of the post content.

By default an excerpt is 55 characters. You can set it to 200 like so:

```
function your_excerpt_length( $length ) {
    return 200;
}
add_filter( 'excerpt_length', 'your_excerpt_length' );
```

This should go into your theme's *functions.php*, ideally.

**EDIT:** To manipulate the excerpt more string, use the following:

```
function your_excerpt_more($more) {
    return '';
}
add_filter('excerpt_more', 'your_excerpt_more');
```

Given that you commented that `the_excerpt()` does not output the native *[...]*, it is likely your theme already makes use of that filter somewhere else to replace the normal output with the described "*… Continue reading →*" link. So rather than adding it again, find that in your theme.

Comment: Anyway to get rid of the "read more" ? I already have a button for that.

Comment: @Trip `the_excerpt()` should display _[...]_ at the end, but not "_read more_". What is the exact string it outputs after the 200 characters? I will update my answer accordingly.

Comment: It gives me a `… Continue reading →` But I don't need those because I already made a button.

Comment: Ah I didn't realize the themes had their own custom functions as well. Thanks so much Johannes!